# (2004 Lincoln Navigator) How to make it beep when I lock the doors?

Tags: ford, key, fob, lincoln, navigator

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07QBYQS7C/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_4N-5Db43Z8A1Y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QBYQS7C)

I just bought this new key and programmed it for my truck, but this new fob doesn’t make it beep when I lock the doors like the original one does. How do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

It should only beep on second press so make sure your sending the lock/unlock signal twice. I'm a little surprised one would make it beep and the other wouldn't but if its not working like it should you can try this to activate/deactivate horn chip , press and hold the lock and unlock buttons simultaneously for 2-3 seconds. You should see the hazard lights flash. Hit the lock button once. Now the horn should honk if activating or not honk if deactivating horn chirp.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn’t work

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Next time I'm working on a navigator or similar system I will poke around it some with IDS and see if its a configurable option. I have not run across it on early fords to know much off hand. Seems odd tho that its just 1 of the 2. Perhaps you could try reprogramming JUST the new remote temporarily to see if it works then. If it does, then it could be related to the positions the remote is stored in..

Comment: The door dingers are sometimes wired to the ignition so I would say it's wired to the horn, which should be on your radiator support. You would have to follow the wiring.